# Can I change a bunch of address points to labeled points without having to do each one separately?

Tags: labeling

I am trying to make a map with all of our customers in a certain area, I got the addresses on the map so now I have 300 dots. I was wondering if there is a way to make those labelled points without having to do all 300 separately? if so could someone please tell me. thanks

Comment: Which software are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Most GIS software have a simple label option to turn labels on or off for all features for a particular layer.

**ArcMap**, right click on the layer in the Table of Contents and select Label Features (also you can define additional labeling optins such as what field is labeled via the layers Properties>Labeling tab).

**QGIS**, right click the layer in the Table of Contents and select Properties>Labels.  Here again you can define various properties for labeling.

Comment: For QGIS, consider using the "New" labeling engine by clicking on the "ABC" button on the LABEL toolbar.  This will give you more flexibility in defining your labels.